# adding fields to OverlayItem

Tags: android, overlayitem

A simple questions about OverlayItem. I my map android application, tapping on a location, I would show some info like: name, infoq, info2, info3. So I extend the OverlayItems:

```
public class NewOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {

    public NewOverlayItem(GeoPoint point, String title, String snippet1, String snippet2, String snippet3) {
        super(point, title, snippet1);

    }

}
```

and I use it :

```
NewOverlayItem overlayitem = new NewOverlayItem(geo, name, oferta, horario, info);
```

Now I don't know how use the    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
in order to show the news snippet.

I have change the definition class:

```
    public class MyOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<MyOverlayItem> { 

...}
```

but the map still show only the first one snipped.

Tx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can extend it to *store* `info2` and `info3`. You will have to arrange to display the data.

Just make sure your `ItemizedOverlay` uses the same type. So, if you extend `OverlayItem` to create `DoxsiOverlayItem`, your `ItemizedOverlay` declaration would use `ItemizedOverlay<DoxsiOverlayItem>` instead of `ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>`.

Comment: Are you saying to create a class that extend overlaY?

Comment: @doxsi: To use `OverlayItem`, you typically use `ItemizedOverlay` rather than `Overlay`.

Comment: Tx. I create a new class DoxsiOverlayItem in oreder to extend OverlayItem. It works but I do not undertand how change the old               itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem1);

Comment: @doxsi: There is no `addOverlay()` method on `ItemizedOverlay`. Please learn how to create a *basic* map application *first*, *then* worry about creating one that use custom `OverlayItem` subclasses and the like.